# Heavy loads of SVG nodes with Raphael

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, svg, raphael

Question: How can I temporally generate Raphael nodes and then inject them in to DOM all at once?

After some time now, I am still stuck here at the SVG/Raphael/DOM problem.

Raphael has been very nice platform for our studio to have some great projects to be done. But when it comes to lots of SVG on one single page, generated with Raphael - what happens with the page is this (and it's the problem itself):

1) Browser  processes .js file with the Raphael code.

2) Raphael finds SVG line in my code and tries to create AND to inject new node directly to DOM.

3) Then it finds the next line of code, and then the next one, and so on...

4) Having more than 6,000 code lines of pure SVG - what happens is Raphael is taking way over too much time processing each and every one of that lines, so in the meantime (for the user) it seams that the browser is stuck (frozen) and is not responding, till Raphael will give it a notice that it has finished to process the code.

So, generally, the scenario that I want to achieve is that:

1) Browser  processes .js file with the Raphael code.

2) Raphael finds SVG line in my code and injects newly created node in to global temporal var, where all of the other node are going to be injected as well.

3) Then it finds the next line of code, and then the next one, and so on, till it will process all of the code, creating many nodes that are stored in a variable.

4) After processing is done - Raphael takes that temp var and dumps it into DOM, creating ALL of the nodes at once. Considering situation with 6000+ nodes - this will drastically increase overall performance. (I know that since I've tries to inject pure SVG code using Chrome in to some of our test pages and it took less than a second to Chrome to process code, comparing to 30+ seconds on Raphael part.)

What have I tried? Well, I've been over [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436501/dom-manipulation-during-large-svg-rendering), giving up 200 of my reputation, but unfortunately, couldn't get any further in this problem.

So, to be clear, my question is: How can I temporally generate Raphael nodes and then inject them in to DOM all at once?

Comment: Is it possible to put a example working bit of code on a jsfiddle to highlight this particular case ?

Comment: Indeed, and thats why I think its important to have just that code in a jsfiddle for people to try and resolve that particular question. Also didn't the previous SO question have the answer, maybe I'm reading it wrong, but again I think a test example that people could modify would help.